# How to capitalize all the long form of an acronym using `acro` package

Tags: acronyms, capitalization, acro

I'm dealing with my acronyms using `acro` package and I want to know how to capitalize all the long acronym form.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{FiME}{
short=FiME,
long=Filtração em Múltiplas Etapas,
}
\begin{document}
I want to capitalize this \Ac{FiME}
with something like this FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS (FiME)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you write the long form all in uppercase?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley Because I just need this form once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `acro` manual, you can use `\acflike` to manually change a one off first-use like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{FiME}{
short=FiME,
long=Filtração em Múltiplas Etapas,
}

\begin{document}
I want to capitalize this \acflike{FiME}{FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS}
with something like this FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS (FiME)
\end{document}
```

I would prefer an automatic method that can be made into a macro, but this method will work for occasional use.

[image: preview of tex code.]

---

OLD ANSWER:

The `acro` package only shows the long form once (at least by default), so you can make the long form uppercase manually.

E.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{FiME}{
short=FiME,
long=FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS,
}
\begin{document}
I want to capitalize this \Ac{FiME}
with something like this FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS (FiME)

Then the second time it's used, it's just an acronym, e.g. \Ac{FiME}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output of tex code.]

Comment: It's O.K. However, if in other section of the document I want to show the long form again, without the capitalization?. Every document section I have to use `\acresetall`

Comment: Edited with a possible way to use `\acflike`.

Comment: @DanielValencia Personally I would consider going for clemens' answer as it's more complete.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the optional argument of `\Ac` to change the format locally:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{FiME}{
short=FiME,
long=Filtração em Múltiplas Etapas,
}
\begin{document}
I want to capitalize this \Ac[long-format=\MakeUppercase]{FiME}
with something like this FILTRAÇÃO EM MÚLTIPLAS ETAPAS (FiME)

\acresetall

\Ac{FiME}

\end{document}
```

[image]